# Why Does GitHub Create Releases for New Tags When I Push Them to It?

Tags: github, release-management, git-tag

GitHub seems to be creating releases out of tags whenever I push those tags up to a GitHub repository that I've cloned to my own machine.  How do I prevent GitHub from doing this?  If I wanted a release, I'd go into GitHub and *create* one from a *pre-existing* tag, but I don't want *all* of my tags to be associated with releases!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything related to disabling this behavior in GitHub's help pages, so I think that it may not be possible to disable this.  The best you can do is [ask their support team](https://github.com/contact) to see if this feature exists or, if that doesn't work, ask for it — the support team's members are awesome and will pay attention to you for sure.

Comment: OK, I let GitHub's support team know about this question (both by repeating it in my help request and by putting a link to this question in it.)

Comment: Did you get any reply from them in the meantime?